# Pandas select top 2 from each group based on absolute value

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
Col1    Col2    Val1
A       a       -13
A       a       -101
A       a        40
A       b        22
B       b        3
B       b       -55
B       b        5
B       b       -27
```

I want to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Val1
A       a      -101
A       a       40
A       b       22
B       b      -55
B       b      -27
```

Where for each group in `Col1` and `Col2` I am selecting the top 2 based on absolute value of `Val1`. I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do:

```
df.loc[df['Val1'].abs().groupby([df['Col1'], df['Col2']])
                       .rank(ascending=False).le(2)]


  Col1 Col2  Val1
1    A    a  -101
2    A    a    40
3    A    b    22
5    B    b   -55
7    B    b   -27
```

Comment: You are missing the pair A, b which gives 22

Comment: another option is to create a pusedo key, but this answer is better - 
   `df.assign(key=df["Val1"].abs().sort_values("key", ascending=False).drop("key", 1).groupby(["Col1", "Col2"]).head(2).sort_values("Col1"))`

Answer (score 0):

Another option using argsort.

```
 df.loc[df['Val1'].abs().argsort()[::-1]].groupby(['Col1','Col2']).head(2).sort_values(by = 'Col1')
```